# write itpc and exif metadata on jpgs vb.net

Tags: vb.net, exif

I need a library that allows me to `write` metadata (ITPC AND EXIF) to a jpg.

I have found a lot of questions here but none with the answer to this question. it seems that there are many outdated libraries but none of them seems to be what i need.

The library i am searching for has to do both itpc and exif and can be a dll or a class to use, but should not have exe files in it. (like the one in written in python that is advised on most questions)

any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why they must be in the same library?

Comment: because i'd like to keep things clean and with as few external DLL's as possible. its also easier to handle if i have only one dll because it will probably use the same set of functions.